# "negotiating a retirement" what is the meaning of "negotiating" here

Tags: meaning, verbs

Full sentence => "Not only did Chin Shih plunder boats, she defeated the British, Chinese and Portuguese natives, before negotiating a long and wealthy retirement for herself"

Comment: Hello, Ezra Yeung, and welcome to English Language & Usage. The answer to your question may well be discoverable simply by looking up the meanings of the verb _negotiate_ in a reputable dictionary. Please consider doing that and then—if you still have questions about what the meaning of "negotiating a retirement" in your quotation is—briefly revise your question to explain why none of the dictionary definitions seems suitable. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The word 'obtain' could be substituted in lieu of negotiation and retain the original meaning within that specific context (or - my understand of it, at least).

Comment: Or maybe "arrange" or "finagle", depending on whether the retirement funds were already acquired, or garnered by some additional ploy.

Comment: Exactly; we shall never know what negotiate means because such arrangements take place behind closed doors.

Comment: Have you evidence to support your understanding?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The context provided by the OP is what I base my understanding on, my justification for my understanding is explained by *Hugh*, above.